# Almost sure convergence implies convergence in quadratic mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

[From Thomas Ferguson, exercise $2.8$] Show if $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s. and if $E(X_{n}^{2}) \rightarrow E(X^2) < \infty$, then $X_n \rightarrow X$ in quadratic mean.

So, I have to prove that $E\left(|X_{n} - X|^2 \right) \rightarrow 0.$ What I was thinking was something like

\begin{eqnarray}
E\left(\left(X_{n} - X\right)^2\right) = E\left(\left(X_{n}^{2} - 2XX_n + X^2\right)\right) &=& E\left(\left(X_{n}^{2} - 2XX_n + 2X^2 - X^2\right)\right)\\ &=& E\left(\left(X_{n}^{2} - X^2 - 2XX_n + 2X^2\right)\right)\\
&=& E\left(\left(X_{n}^{2} - X^2\right)\right) - E\left(\left(2XX_n - 2X^2\right)\right).
\end{eqnarray}
Now I know that $E\left(\left(X_{n}^{2} - X^2\right)\right) \rightarrow 0$ from the hypotesis. But I don't know what to do with the other term and how to relate it with the a.s. convergence.

I know this problem may be related to the Scheffe or Riesz theorem (or dominated convergence), but I was thinking if this could be achieved using straightforward probability calculations without any result from measure theory. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use Fatoo lemma with $$Y_n=2|X_n|^2+2|X^2|-|X-X_n|^2.$$

Comment: I understand the hint, but in order to use Fatou's lemma I need the $Y_n$ to converge almost sure to something. Is it correct if I say that $Y_n \rightarrow 4|X|^2$ almost sure?

Comment: @Jeybe: yes of course